# How can I see an image of an edge labeled graph from GraphData?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

If I input:

```
g = {"CompleteBipartite", {2, 3}}; 
{GraphData[g, "LabeledImage"], GraphData[g, "EdgeList"]}
```

then I can see a graph with its vertices labeled.  I want to see the edges labeled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the property `"LabeledGraph"` and wrap the output with `Graph` and add the desired options:

```
Graph[GraphData[{"CompleteBipartite", {2, 3}}, "LabeledGraph"], 
 EdgeLabels -> Placed[Automatic, .7]]
```

[image]

**Note:** The property `"LabeledGraph"` is not listed in `GraphData["Properties"]`:

```
MemberQ[GraphData["Properties"], "LabeledGraph"]
```

> False

Answer (score 4):

You are probably better off controlling the output `Graph` object directly. Note how to place labels so they do not overlap with `Placed`. Read up on [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphsAndNetworks.html).

```
SetProperty[
    GraphData[{"CompleteBipartite", {2, 3}}],
{VertexLabels->Automatic,
EdgeLabels->Placed[Automatic,.7]}]
```

[image]